# Version 1.2.4 incompatible with framework 4.0

Tags: breeze

I was rebuilding my app from scratch today and was using NuGet to install breeze into my app and it failed on a dependency.  For the next couple of releases I am forced to use framework 4.0 instead of 4.5.  Is there a work around for the dependency issue?

```
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost (≥ 5.0.0-alpha-130319 && ≤ 5.0.65535.65535)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core (≥ 5.0.0-alpha-130319 && ≤ 5.0.65535.65535)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client (≥ 5.0.0-alpha-130319 && ≤ 5.0.65535.65535)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Data.OData (≥ 5.2.0 && < 5.3.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'System.Spatial (= 5.2.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Data.Edm (= 5.2.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'WebActivator'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure (≥ 1.0.0.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'EntityFramework (≥ 4.4 && < 6.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Q'.
Successfully installed 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client 5.0.0-alpha-130319'.
Successfully installed 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core 5.0.0-alpha-130319'.
Successfully installed 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost 5.0.0-alpha-130319'.
Successfully installed 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi 5.0.0-alpha-130319'.
Successfully installed 'System.Spatial 5.2.0'.
Successfully installed 'Microsoft.Data.Edm 5.2.0'.
Successfully installed 'Microsoft.Data.OData 5.2.0'.
Successfully installed 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData 5.0.0-alpha-130319'.
Successfully installed 'WebActivator 1.5.3'.
Successfully installed 'Q 0.9.2'.
Successfully installed 'Breeze.WebApi 1.2.4'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Updating 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost 4.0.20710.0' to 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost 5.0.0-alpha-130319' failed. Unable to find a version of 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage' that is compatible with 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost 5.0.0-alpha-130319'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Breeze should work just fine with .NET 4.  To confirm this just create a new ASP.NET MVC4 Web Api project targeted at .NET 4 and add either of the breeze nuget packages. Either should install and work without problems.

I am guessing that you have some old nuget package refs in your project.  For example I see refs to "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost (≥ 5.0.0-alpha ... ".  Breeze itself has no dependency on any "alpha" nuget packages.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Also ... make sure your Web.config has the following  redirect:

```
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
       <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
```